# Connecting Apache Superset with Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, hiveql, apache-superset

I've my Hadoop cluster running in AWS environment where the schema got mapped with Hive. And I could see the complete Data in Hive.
Now, Here is the Problem - I am trying to connect my hive to Superset where I couldn't able to connect with.

This is how I have provided my URI:

```
jdbc+hive://MYIP:PORT
```

Also tried:

```
hive://username:password@MYIP:PORT
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure hive server2 is up and running

Also you can try this one

> hive://hostname:10000/default?auth=NOSASL

Comment: what is the hostname? In my case I am running both hive and superset a two separate docker images?

Comment: It's the IP / hostname of Hive server / Docker Image

Comment: I guess if it's running in your local will be localhost

Comment: how to specify username & password?